# how to retrieve identity auto number of table of microsoft sql server

Tags: database

i have 2 tables

Purchase   has field **InvoiceNo** which is identity auto number

PurchaseProduct has fields **PurchaseProduct_No** which is identity auto number 
and **InvoiceNo** from Purchase

for concurrency
i plan to insert like this

```
        sqlTran = conn.BeginTransaction();
        try
        {
            insert statments for Purchase
            insert statments for PurchaseProduct
            sqlTran.Commit();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            sqlTran.Rollback();

        }
```

but how do i get InvoiceNo value of Purchase table
to insert InvoiceNo in PurchaseProduct table since it is autonumber?

Comment: This might help: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/

Comment: Assuming MSSQL Server but please make sure to specify which RDBMS system you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft SQL server records the last auto-generated identity value in the [@@IDENTITY system variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx). You can select that to get the value that you're interested in after the insert.

```
-- Statement to Create Table
CREATE TABLE Purchase(
   InvoiceNo INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
 , Product NVARCHAR(128))


-- Insert Statement
INSERT INTO Purchase
   (Product)
  VALUES
   ('Test Product A')
GO
-- Get the auto-generate InvoiceNo for last inserted record
SELECT @@IDENTITY as [InvoiceNo]
```

Comment: I've added a sameple but you really should look at the MSDN page I've linked to. There are other identity-related functions to conside. And finally, you should consider not using an auto-generated field and instead generating unique invoice numbers yourself.